# How to Require ALL of Jasmine Library with CucumberJS?

Tags: typescript, jasmine, cucumber, cucumberjs

I want to unit test using Jasmine and CucumberJS for my Angular v9 application. Following the [tutorial from cucumber.io](https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/10-minute-tutorial/), I've setup cucumber as the default runner. Unable to use jasmine methods though. Figured out how to use expect method but need access to the rest of the Jasmine library like `spyOn` and `createSpyObj`. When I execute line: `expect(this.actualAnswer).toBe(expectedAnswer);` error is thrown saying `TypeError: Cannot read property 'toBe' of undefined at World.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\cukejas\features\step_definitions\stepdefs.js:24:28)`

Here's what I have so far. Can someone help please?

`stepdefs.js`

```
const assert = require('assert');
const { Given, When, Then } = require('cucumber');
const expect = require('C:\\Users\\User\\cukejas\\node_modules\\jasmine\\lib\\jasmine.js');

function isItFriday(today) {
  if (today === "Friday") {
    return "TGIF";
  } else {
    return "Nope";
  }
}

Given('today is {string}', function (givenDay) {
  this.today = givenDay;
});

When('I ask whether it\'s Friday yet', function () {
  this.actualAnswer = isItFriday(this.today);
});

Then('I should be told {string}', function (expectedAnswer) {
  // assert.equal(this.actualAnswer, expectedAnswer);
  //expect(1); --> This line executes without error
  expect(this.actualAnswer).toBe(expectedAnswer); // error thrown here
});
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "cukejas",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "./node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js -p default",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "~9.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "~9.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "~9.0.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.900.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.0.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.0.1",
    "@types/cucumber": "^6.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "cucumber": "^6.0.5",
    "cucumber-pretty": "^6.0.0",
    "cucumber-tsflow": "^3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.18.0",
    "typescript": "~3.7.5"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Jasmine and CucumberJS are both test runners, so unfortunately you can't use both frameworks at the same time. However, you can use the [expect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/expect) package (part of [Jest](https://jestjs.io)) which has a similar API:

```js
const expect = require('expect');
```

Online example: https://testjam.io/?p=D11o5cwOIQukGy1F6GRU

Alternatively, [chai](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chai) is another wonderful library which supports expressive assertions.

As far as `spyOn`, you may consider using a standalone library such as [sinon](https://sinonjs.org/).

Comment: Hi. Saw your testament link. Thanks for that. Can you show me an example that uses CucumberJS and Sinon `spyOn` as well so I know how to configure it myself please?

Comment: Here's a nice [comparison article between Jasmine and Sinon](https://www.clairecodes.com/blog/2016-02-15-spies-in-jasmine-and-sinon/). As far as using it with CucumberJS, you just have to `require()` it in your js file and then use it in your step definitions.